# Writing to table storage continuously replacing entity from one tabel to another table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a webjob writing to table storage. My webjob writes to two tables one after the other. As webjob runs asynchronously some times the entity from one table is replaced in another table. Is this because of asynchronous operation?

TableOperation op1 = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity1); 
_table1.Execute(op1);

TableOperation op2 = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity2); 
_table2.Execute(op2);

The enity1 is storing in table2 sometimes instead of table1.

If I place Thread.sleep(5000) after writing to first table then everything is fine. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

@BhanuReddy, the function `CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation)` is not an asynchronous operation, please see the `Execute` code in the class [`CloudTable`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/6152eb5fe3264eaa12117977edcf971b8c3debd2/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Table/CloudTable.cs#L49) & [`TableOperation`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/6152eb5fe3264eaa12117977edcf971b8c3debd2/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Table/TableOperation.cs#L35). Meanwhile, there is no more code in your question, so I can't determine the cause of the issue.

My suggestion is that you can wrap two group of objects & operations for replaceing entity into two alone function to isolate with partial variables.

If you can post the complete code of your webjob, I think it's very helpful for figuring out the logical issue.